# Laravel Many to many relation joining tables issue

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to build an app for university students.

My idea is to retrieve data from the database, where for each student should be displayed courses depending on which semester the student is. In other words if student A is in second semester and let's say the course Databases is being held only in second semester, for student A I should have on the page only Databases as eligible course.

I have the following tables:

-users

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

-semester

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('semesters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('number');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

additional_info_students

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('additional_info_students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('first_name', 255);
        $table->string('last_name', 255);
        $table->integer('faculty_number')->unique();        
        $table->integer('group_number');
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->integer('semester_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('semester_id')->references('id')->on('semesters');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

-courses

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('language', 10);
        $table->longText('description', 30000000);
        $table->integer('semester_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('semester_id')->references('id')->on('semesters');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

-courses_assign_students

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses_assign_students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('user_id')->on('additional_info_students');
        $table->integer('courses_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('courses_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
        $table->timestamps();
    });     
}
```

Would this work? I can not seem to join them correctly in order to get what I need.

Moreover when I join the tables and try to print a property from the collection like student_id, I am getting an error undefined property.

```php
public function showAll() {
    $courses = CoursesAssignStudents::join('courses', 'courses_assign_students.courses_id', '=', 'courses.id')
                       ->join('additional_info_students', 'courses_assign_students.student_id', '=', 'additional_info_students.user_id')
                       ->select('courses.*','additional_info_students.user_id as student_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'faculty_number','group_number','year','additional_info_students.semester_id as sem_id')->get();

    return view('courses', compact('courses'));
}
```

Also by passing the data in the view, I am looping through courses and I am getting the same course twice, when I should get it once.

Lastly, I am using Laravel 5.4

I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to set the relationship in your model. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: hi how are your models relations set up? Also note that in order to access data from the table between many to many you have to use the pivot, eg : $courses->pivot->student_id, aside from that what is it that you can't do more precisely?

Comment: Hi GaimZz, I haven't set relationships in the models. I am trying to pass data to the view. I want to display for each student the correct courses depending on the semester. So if a student is second semester and courses DB and Math are in second semester, I want to have DB and Math. Currently the courses are displayed twice. DB DB Math Math. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you show how your looping in your view file?

Comment: This is the way I do it:                                                                                 @foreach($courses as $course)
   <div id = '{{$course->name}}'><a href="#">
    <img class="thumbnail"  src="{{asset ('images/'.$course->name.'.png')}}" alt='{{$course->name}}'/>
   </a></div>
 @endforeach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not do it like that.
you have students table (users) here
and as you said: each student should be displayed courses depending on which semester the student is in.

> which means
>
> Student must be in a semester
>
> Courses must be related to a semester.

so you only need to change this table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses_assign_students', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('student_id')->references('user_id')->on('additional_info_students');
       $table->integer('courses_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('courses_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
       $table->timestamps();
     });     
}
```

The relation should be between courses and semesters. 
so the table will be like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('course_semester', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->integer('semester_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('semester_id')->references('id')->on('semesters');
       $table->integer('courses_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('courses_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
       $table->timestamps();
     });     
}
```

so now you have a

> **student** which *belongs* to a **semester** 
>   and 
>   you have **semester** which *has many* **courses.**

so you can translate this to relations in **models** instead of using this function showAll().
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this and see what will happen :)

Comment: So I tried and wasn't able to extract what I need. I have created the pivot table as mentioned above. Have added the relationships in the models. How can I now retrive the courses for each student?

Comment: first, your relations must be as the following:
in user model

public function Semester()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Semester');
}

in  Semester model:

public function courses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Course');
}

so you can easily retrieve them using the following line
$semester = $user->Semester;
then 
$courses = $semester->courses;

or 

$coursesForStudent = $user->Semester->courses;

May be you can use hasManyThrough.